# Image found but not visible Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, canvas, express

I have a canvas and in the canvas I want to load an image.

client.js

```
game.viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
    game.card1 = document.getElementById('card1');

        //Adjust their size
    game.viewport.width = game.world.width;
    game.viewport.height = game.world.height;

    game.card1.width = game.cards.width;
    game.card1.height = game.cards.height;

        //Fetch the rendering contexts
    game.ctx = game.viewport.getContext('2d');
    game.ctx2 = game.card1.getContext('2d');
```

game_core.js

```
 game_core.prototype.client_cards = function(game_instance) {
this.instance = game_instance;
var img = new Image();
img.src = '/images/Chainlinks/AddBurn.png';
this.ctx2.drawImage(img,10,20);
this.ctx2.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)';
this.ctx2.fillText('Summoner: '+player1, 10 , 20);
```

The text Summnor2: is visible in the canvas but the image isn't drawed. If I look in de cmd of node.js he finds the image path. so I really don't know where it goes wrong.

Comment: try `img.src = './images/Chainlinks/AddBurn.png';`

Comment: didn't fix the problem he returns code: 200 green so thats good. but still not vissible

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Make sure image path is correct.

```
var self = this;
var img = new Image();
img.src = './images/Chainlinks/AddBurn.png';
img.onload = function() {
  self.ctx2.drawImage(img,10,20);
  self.ctx2.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)';
  self.ctx2.fillText('Summoner: '+player1, 10 , 20);
};
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'drawImage' of undefined

Comment: I checked trough console.log img.src is a direct link to an image.

Comment: hi thank you works perfect.maybe you could help me with something else. the image is just the front. do you know how i could couple extra data to the image. Like attack and deffence?

Comment: you can thank me by accepting the answer :) and post new question for other issues

Comment: yeah i know but  i already tried and i need 15 rep to do that i am sorry:(